# Ionic 2 File Plugin usage examples

Tags: file, typescript, angular, cordova-plugins, ionic2

Does anyone have complete examples about how to use the Cordova Native File Plugin in a Ionic 2/Angular 2 project?

I installed this plugin but the documentation don't seems to make much sense to me due the fact it is fragmented and lacks of a complete example, including all needed imports.

For example, the following example don't shows where objects like LocalFileSystem or window came from.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
    fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

        console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
        // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
        writeFile(fileEntry, null);

    }, onErrorCreateFile);

}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

For example, I need to crate a property file. First I need to check if a file exists on app sandbox storage area, if don't exists I must create it. Then I must open the file write data and save it . How could I do that?

Comment: can you be more specific regarding what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: For example, I need to crate a property file. First I need to check if a file exists on app sandbox storage area, if don't exists I must create it. Then I must open the file write data and save it .

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/file-datadirectory-static-in-ionic-native-can-not-be-found-by-typescript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ionic 2 comes with a Cordova file plugin wrapper:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/.

The necessary file system paths (e.g. `cordova.file.applicationDirectory`) you can find here at the documentation of the original plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files. Note that not all platforms support the same storage paths.

I even managed to build a file browser with it. Use it like so:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {File} from 'ionic-native';

...

File.listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory, 'mySubFolder/mySubSubFolder').then(
  (files) => {
    // do something
  }
).catch(
  (err) => {
    // do something
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! That was one of my doubts. Where do this cordova object come from?

Comment: The compiler will give you a message but the cordova object is available on your device using Ionic.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm get a blank screen and and an error message in the console. The message says: TypeScript error: E:/Ionic2/ionic2-app/app/providers/file-provider/file-provider.ts(22,18): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'cordova'.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot test this in a browser, it has to be on the device/emulator. You can also use `declare var cordova: any` after the imports to soothe the compiler.

Comment: How could I to write to a file? I don't find any method to do this.

Comment: It seems, at the moment you can only replace a file with `createFile(path, fileName, true)`.

Comment: I try with images, but the images not showing, how I read images?

Comment: i tried to create folder to my mobile internal storage but i get error code 5  File.createDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, "new_dir", false) - @tyftler

Comment: I'm getting this JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'applicationDirectory' of undefined or null reference. Anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: @DeepuVarghese Use cordova.file.dataDirectory

Comment: Hi can you tell how can I delete a video from the file system?

Comment: I had print that files variable, but its showing [object object], Please tell me what should I print

Answer (score 10):

Here is an example using IonicNative for an app I am working on where I want
to send an email with a csv file attachment.

```
import {EmailComposer} from '@ionic-native/email-composer';
import {File} from '@ionic-native/file';

class MyComponent {
 constructor(private emailComposer: EmailComposer, private file: File) {

 }
 testEmail() {
 this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'test.csv', 'hello,world,', {replace: true})
     .then(() => {      
       let email = {
         to: 'email@email',
         attachments: [
           this.file.dataDirectory + 'test.csv'
         ],

         subject: 'subject',
         body: 'body text...',
         isHtml: true
       };
       this.emailComposer.open(email);

     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.error(err);
     });

 }
}
```

This was tested with ionic 3.7.0 on IOS.

Comment: it didn't work with me when i used dataDirectory , but it worked when I used externalDirectory

Comment: @Amr.Ayoub perhaps something changed in the API.  thanks for the comment.

Comment: This works. But only if you write / read a file from the root directory. I my case I can't create any folder. In worst case I want to create a deep path. But how? The examples from the docs does not work.

Comment: @PhilipBrack is there any way to write file inside `this.file.applicationDirectory`?

Comment: I tried the same in windows 10 uwp app, email is opening with body & subject,  but the attachment not working ,  any idea?