# How to write all console logs to a file in angular2 / ionic2 apps

Tags: angular, ionic2

Please feel free to share anything you know or have found on 
"How to write all console logs to a file in angular2 / ionic2"

I'm already using angular2-logger and I need to write the logs to a file

Thanks

Comment: Using only angular2, it's impossible since angular2 is pure client, so you're not supposed to write files. But using ionic2 you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276072/ionic-2-file-plugin-usage-examples

Comment: you have to send the data to a server. Then, server side, you can append a file.

Comment: Thanks mate, I decided to store a queue of logs on local storage