# could not bring image to view were image captured by cordovaplugin

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I followed this link  [Ionic 2 File Plugin usage examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276072/ionic-2-file-plugin-usage-examples) to take picture and store it to a target folder inside my internal memory and i tested it it works good, next i am trying to list out all files inside that folder i done it but i could not bring it to view,

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item><img  [src]="file"  *ngFor="let file in myFiles"></ion-item>
  </ion-list>


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    import { NavController, AlertController, ActionSheetController, ToastController, Platform, LoadingController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Camera } from 'ionic-native';
    import { File } from 'ionic-native';
    import { FilePath } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    file;
    public base64Image: string;
    myFiles: string[];

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public alertCtrl: AlertController){}
    listImage(){
            console.log("list image files");
            var fileSystem = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
            var folderpath = fileSystem + "Vanan Audio/";
            console.log("img",folderpath);
            File.listDir(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, 'vanan Audio').then(
              (allFiles) => {
                // do something
                console.log(allFiles);
                var i =0
                console.log(allFiles[i+1].name);
                for (i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) { 
                    console.log(allFiles[i].name);
                    console.log(allFiles[i].nativeURL);

                }
                  this.myFiles = allFiles;
                return allFiles
              }
            ).catch(
              (err) => {
                // do something
              }
            );
        }
  }
```

now i could take picture and stored it to a folder using external root Directory, i could list out file name using loop, I need to show all images inside that folder to my ionic view

i an getting error statement while i run it on to my device

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1223
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("


    <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let file in myFiles">

        <img [src]="file.nativeURL"/>
"): HomePage@28:9.............................
```

Comment: cant you just set in a component variable and use that in the html?

Comment: could u tell me how to do it.

Comment: is the function in the provider or component? else you will have to chain the promise

Comment: Check my updated question @ suraj . I have not added any providers or services just added plugin and woring with my .ts file, i think i have not done it correctly i am getting err when my device loads i checked using inspect element, and in my mobile i get only a white screen

Comment: not inside the loop .. you dont need loop since your class vairable `myFiles` is an array

Comment: and in html make it `file.nativeURL`

Comment: getting error "Type 'string' is not assignable to any[]"

Comment: you are trying to assign inside the loop..look at the answer.. directly assign the array.. or do `this.myFiles.push(allFiles[i])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134942/discussion-between-yokesh-varadhan-and-suraj).

Comment: my mistake sry.. its `let file of myFiles` not in

Comment: is it solved? better to close the question and mark it if so..

Comment: thnks it worked well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an array of file paths in the component:

```
myFiles:any[];//assign empty array in constructor
```

In the `File.listDir then` (assuming `listImage()` is in component):

```
this.myFiles = allFiles;
```

In the html,

```
<div *ngFor="let file of myFiles">
 <img [src]="file.nativeURL"/>
</div>
```