# in Ionic 2, How should I store images?

Tags: ionic2

I am making an hybrid mobile app using Ionic 2, in which I am pretty new. In the app I have to show images from distant URLs after sending a query that returns the list of URLs for the images to show (this part is OK). But I was wondering, because I want my app to work offline (after having used it online at least once for some initial data), how should I store the images using `@ionic/storage`'s `Storage` provider ?

Can I consider saving base64 strings in ionic key/value SQLite / IndexedDB default storage or is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the plugin `cordova-plugin-file`.

The usage is well described here : [Ionic 2 File Plugin usage examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276072/ionic-2-file-plugin-usage-examples)